# How do you define custom attributes for the LayoutParams class of a custom RecyclerView.LayoutManager implementation?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, custom-attributes, android-custom-attributes

I know how to create custom attributes for specific classes.  You simply define them in a Styleable using the class name for the name, like so.

```
<declare-styleable name="MyCustomView">
    <attr name="customAttr1" format="integer" />
    <attr name="customAttr2" format="boolean" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Then, when I use instances of `MyCustomView` in my layouts, `customAttr1` and `customAttr2` are available to set.  Easy enough.

What I'm trying to do now is use custom attributes for the `LayoutParams` on the children of my custom `RecyclerView`, or more accurately, in the root view of the layout files that feed the individual `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` subclasses I'm using. However, I can't get the attributes handed to me and I'm not sure why not.

Here's my attrs.xml file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="ScrollableGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams">
        <attr name="cellLayoutMode">
            <enum name="scrollable"                 value="0" />
            <enum name="fixedHorizontal"            value="1" />
            <enum name="fixedVertical"              value="2" />
            <enum name="fixedHorizontalAndVertical" value="3" />
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

Here's the code in my custom LayoutParams class that reads the attributes...

```
public LayoutParams(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){

    super(context, attrs);

    TypedArray styledAttrs = context.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.ScrollableGridLayoutManager_LayoutParams);

    if(styledAttrs.hasValue(R.styleable.ScrollableGridLayoutManager_LayoutParams_cellLayoutMode)){
        int layoutModeOrdinal = styledAttrs.getInt(R.styleable.ScrollableGridLayoutManager_LayoutParams_cellLayoutMode, layoutMode.ordinal());
        layoutMode = LayoutMode.values()[layoutModeOrdinal];
    }

    styledAttrs.recycle();
}
```

And here's where I'm setting it in the layout for one of my ViewHolders...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app     = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
    android:background="#0000FF"
    app:cellLayoutMode="fixedVertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mainTextView"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFF00"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

However, nothing I try seems to ever go inside the 'hasValue' call.  It always returns like it isn't set.

Note: I've also tried all of these when defining the attributes...

```
<declare-styleable name="LayoutParams">

<declare-styleable name="ScrollableGridLayoutManager_LayoutParams">

<declare-styleable name="ScrollableGridAdapter_LayoutParams">
```

...but none seem to work.

So what am I doing wrong?  How do you define attributes specific to your custom `LayoutParams` class?

Comment: Pretty much the exact same way. `LayoutParams` subclasses should have a constructor that takes a `Context` and an `AttributeSet`, so you can retrieve those values just like you would in a `View` subclass. Make sure to override `generateLayoutParams(AttributeSet)` in the custom `RecyclerView` to return your `LayoutParams` subclass. Also, though you can use whatever you like, I believe the convention is to append `_Layout` to the custom `ViewGroup`'s `name` for the `LayoutParams`' `<declare-styleable>`; e.g., `name="MyCustomView_Layout"`.

Comment: I've just added my code which does exactly that.  The problem is I'm not sure how to *define* the attributes because no matter what I do in my layout files, the attributes I set are *not* reflected in the attributes passed to the custom LayoutParams constructor. They always report as not being set. That's the issue I'm trying to overcome. (I have a feeling I posted that code while you were answering so you may not have seen it.)

Comment: Hmm, well, I just threw together a quick and dirty test with a `RecyclerView` to make sure I wasn't overlooking anything, and it works as expected. How exactly are you inflating the item layout? Are you passing the parent custom `RecyclerView` in the `inflate()` call?

Comment: Oh, wait, I see it now. You're using the wrong `obtainStyledAttributes()` overload. That is, you forgot to pass the `AttributeSet` to it. Should be `context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ScrollableGridLayoutManager_LayoutParams);`.

Comment: Duh!!! [face-palm]  I feel like an idiot!  How did I not see that?  Question though... which should be the correct value for the name attribute in the declare-styleable tag... or does it matter (i.e. there's no wrong answer and it's just a convention?)

Comment: Yeah, just convention, as far as I'm aware. You can name it anything you want, 'cause it's only gonna be used right there in your XML and code. After processing and compilation, it's all just `int`s anyway. This is from the perspective of only the framework and your code, though. There might be some code analysis tools or some such that expect exactly that name format. Glad that got it working. I'll post an answer here in a minute. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the custom `LayoutParams` constructor, the `obtainStyledAttributes()` call must include the `AttributeSet` passed in. Otherwise, it's pulling values from just the `Context`'s theme, and those attribute values specified in the layout XML won't be included in the returned `TypedArray`.

For example:

```
TypedArray styledAttrs =
    context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ScrollableGridLayoutManager_LayoutParams);
```